# Relative path for contents of <style> tag

Tags: html

**Is there a way to change the "current working directory" of the contents of a
`<script>` tag?**  The directory structure on my server looks like:

```
├── css
│   ├── flexigrid.css
│   └── images
│       ├── bg.gif
│       ├── ...
│       └── wbg.gif
└── js
    └── flexigrid.js

3 directories, 21 files
```

So if I just had the following tag in my `<head>` I would be okay:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/flexigrid.css' />
```

But I am loading the contents of the file as text and inserting them into the
head w/ javascript:

```
// 'css' is a string containing the text of flexigrid.css
var css_el = document.createElement('style');
css_el.type = 'text/css';
css_el.innerHTML = css;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css_el);
```

As a result, lines like this in the stylesheet:

```
background: #eee url(images/line.gif) repeat-y -1px top;
```

load URLs like `/images/line.gif` instead of `/css/images/line.gif`.  Is there
a way to create the `<style>` tag such that the `url()` calls start in the
`/css` directory instead of the base directory *without having to
search-and-replace in javascript*?

Comment: Ah, I missed the final sentence. Is there a reason that you're using JavaScript to insert the `style` but don't want to use JavaScript to properly format/present the inserted `style`s?

Comment: I'm loading the stylesheet w/ javascript because I want to create self-contained plugins that use js/html/css but consist of only one 'require()' type call.  I'm working on a large code base where I don't know about each css file, and if I just use '.replace()' on the css contents I could easily introduce bugs (for example if the file contained paths to both images/ and images/some-other-plugin/images/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ability and caching of the CSS are two major things you lose when you include CSS inline.

One thing you can do for tiny images, like a bullet or line, is convert them to a [data: URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Url), and not worry about relative URLs.

Comment: I thought that the file would still be cached even though I'm loading the contents as text instead of CSS.  For example, if I hit the 'refresh' button several times, the server logs indicate that the browser is not re-requesting the css file in question.

Comment: What CSS file? The HTML file containing the CSS text is cached, but if you use the same CSS text in several HTML files, the server has to send it in each HTML file, since the browser (or proxy, or server) can't cache *part* of a page.

Comment: I'm loading the CSS file as text, and then inserting that as the inner HTML of a <style> tag.  Using this technique the browser is still caching the CSS file (the server only gets a request for the CSS the first time the browser loads the page).  So it seems like I'm still getting caching, but I'm not getting the benefits of the relative path.

Comment: Oh, so modifying the DOM via script, not a server-side include of the CSS?

Comment: Yeah, CSS doesn't have a `@base url(…)` command, so since you are bypassing the browser's built-in support for CSS-relative URLs, you'll need to do something like `replace(/url\(images/g,'url(/css/images')` to the CSS before injecting it, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually you could create a .htaccess file with mod_rewrite directives.

But I think a way with JavaScript or CSS is not possible.

Comment: A way with JavaScript is possible, with [tag:html] and [tag:css] it isn't.